# sorting lists in python using merge sort

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I have here a code for sorting lists using merge sort.. I just got it somewhere in the net.. But honestly, I can't follow the flow of the code... I mean, I can't get how it is implemented. I can understand some part especially the first one where it divides the entire list in two and then sort each side of the list. And then what?? Will you please tell what's happening here? Thank you. :)

```
def merge(badlist):
    if len(badlist) == 1:  
    return badlist  
    m = len(badlist)/2  
    l = merge(badlist[:m])  
    r = merge(badlist[m:])  
    if not len(l) or not len(r):  
        return l or r  
    result = []  
    i = j = 0  
    while (len(result) < len(r) + len(l)):  
        if l[i] < r[j]:  
            result.append(l[i])  
            i += 1  
        else:  
            result.append(r[j])  
            j += 1  
        if i == len(l) or j == len(r):  
            result.extend(l[i:] or r[j:]) 
            break  
    return result  
print merge(badlist)
```

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort, and if so, which part was unclear?

Comment: You cant understand Merging ?

Comment: The wikipedia-article explains all details. I think it would make much sense to repeat it. There are few algorithms around that have been explained more often than mergesort (quicksort is the only more popular I can think of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going line by line,

```
if not len(l) or not len(r):  
        return l or r
```

This checks whether either of the lists is empty. If it is, then the other list is returned.

```
result = []  
i = j = 0
```

Here, `result` and `i`,`j` are initialized

```
while (len(result) < len(r) + len(l)):
```

Runs the `while` loop till all elements of both lists have been copied to the `result` list.

```
    if l[i] < r[j]:  
            result.append(l[i])  
            i += 1  
    else:  
            result.append(r[j])  
            j += 1
```

This block checks which of `l[i]` or `r[j]` is lesser and then appends it to `result`, and advances the respective counter. This goes on till either of the lists gets completely used up, which is checked for in the following code block :

```
    if i == len(l) or j == len(r):  
            result.extend(l[i:] or r[j:]) 
            break
```

Now, whichever list still contains elements, is appended to the end of `result` list as is.

```
return result
```

After which `result` is returned.

As mentioned, the indentation is incorrect in your sample, which I have corrected here.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. By the way, I just can't indent my code here correctly.. but in my computer, i've intended what is meant to be intended. Anyway, thank you so much :)